# How do I get Android Spinner Text to Update?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-spinner

I have a spinner inside my activity.

[image: spinner]

The top spinner bar is to act as a title, I then have a navigation bar below that and in the bottom half I have a fragment container.

The spinner contains a list of all of the exercises which it is passed.

[image]

After clicking one of the items inside the spinner drop down, I would like the spinner text to be updated, however no change occurs...

I get the following messages:

`W/e.exerciseappv: Accessing hidden field Landroid/widget/AbsListView;->mIsChildViewEnabled:Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)`

`D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xc6707410 (DropDownListView) with handle 0xc6e4a5f0`

How can I get my basic spinner working (alternatively does anyone have a work-around) ?

**Activity**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import com.example.exerciseappv5.Fragments.ExerciseGraphFragment;
import com.example.exerciseappv5.Fragments.RecordExerciseFragment;
import com.example.exerciseappv5.Fragments.RecordExerciseHistoryFragment;
import com.example.exerciseappv5.ViewModels.ChildExerciseViewModel;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RecordExerciseActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    List<String> allChildExerciseNames = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String PARENT_EXERCISE_ID = "-999";
    public static final String EXTRA_DATE = "com.example.exerciseappv4.EXTRA_DATE";
    public static final String EXTRA_WEEK_DATES = "1";
    public static String EXTRA_JUNCTIONID = "EXERCISE_JUNCTION_ID";
    int parentExerciseID;
    private ChildExerciseViewModel childExerciseViewModel;
    String firstExerciseName;
    String selectedExercise;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_exercise);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.hasExtra(PARENT_EXERCISE_ID)) {
            parentExerciseID = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(PARENT_EXERCISE_ID));
        }

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.top_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container2, new RecordExerciseFragment()).commit();

        //getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);
        childExerciseViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ChildExerciseViewModel.class);
        childExerciseViewModel.getChildExerciseNameFromParentID(parentExerciseID).observe(this, this::setChildExerciseName);
        childExerciseViewModel.getAllchildExercisesFromParentID(parentExerciseID).observe(this, this::getAllChildExercisesFromParentID);


        Spinner spinner =  findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayList<String> spinnerStringArray = new ArrayList<>();
        //Add your data to your array
        spinnerStringArray.addAll(allChildExerciseNames);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, allChildExerciseNames);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectedExercise = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), selectedExercise, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("spinner item clicked ", selectedExercise);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_track:
                            selectedFragment = new RecordExerciseFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_history:
                            selectedFragment = new RecordExerciseHistoryFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_exercise_list:
                            selectedFragment = new ExerciseGraphFragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container2, selectedFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
            };

    private void setChildExerciseName(String childExerciseName) {
        firstExerciseName = childExerciseName;
    }

    public String getSelectedExercise() {
        return selectedExercise;
    }

    private void getAllChildExercisesFromParentID(List<String> allChildExercisesReceived) {
        allChildExerciseNames.addAll(allChildExercisesReceived);
    }
}
```

**Activity Layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <View style="@style/Full_Divider"
        android:id="@+id/divider9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"/>

    <View style="@style/Full_Divider"
        android:id="@+id/divider10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_navigation" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider10" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/top_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"
        app:menu="@menu/top_navigation"
        android:background="#292929" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**build.Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.exerciseappv5"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
    def room_version = "1.1.1"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'




    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'

    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Comment: Does the Toast with the selected exercise appear?

Comment: No the toast does not appear, nor does the Log

Comment: please add the dpendencies (build.gradle) as well as the imports in RecordExerciseActivity2 - and one more question: which Android version does your device/ emulator have?

Comment: I have added your requests. My device is a Nexus 6P API 30

Comment: This is extremely weird... I managed to reproduce your error: selecting an item has no effect on `android.widget.Spinner` for a device with API level 30. Then I added another Spinner to the layout, this time an `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner`. Now *both Spinners* work, and I can't make them "not work" again...even if I remove the androix-Spinner and clean the project or do "Files-> invalidate caches and restart" on AS)... I've no idea why, but I think switching over from `android.widget.Spinner` to `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner` in the xml will solve the problem.

Comment: I am extremely confused as to what is going on here, I have changed to `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner` however no luck :(

Comment: @BömachtBlau, According to documentation of `AppCompatSpinner`, "**This will automatically be used when you use Spinner in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.**"

Comment: @JoshBrett but in code, you are still creating object with `Spinner` class. I have also post a possible solution to this problem. Please, check it out.

Comment: @cgb_pandey - that's correct, one should not use AppCompatSpinner in a layout file, simply Spinner will do. But please note that I tried to communicate what I did to analyse the issue, and that after adding the AppCompatSpinner I stopped being able to reproduce the error, even after removing it from the project and cleaning / rebuilding the project. I admit that my last sentence can be read as a recommendation (at least if you feel encouraged to try something when someone tells you "I've no idea...") but it was not meant that way (cont)

Comment: (cont) Without being able to reliably reproduce the error, I had to stop working on the problem, but I hoped my results might help others to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are doing the whole setup for the `Spinner` in `onCreate()`: you instantiate the adapter with a (possibly empty) data list and call `spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);`

After that you only change the data list: each time that `getAllChildExercisesFromParentID(List<String>)` is called, you add a couple of `String`s to the data list which you passed into the adapter. But you never call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the adapter, and I think this is where things start going wrong.

The runtime does not throw an `Exception` (as would have been the case with `ListView` instead of `Spinner` if I remember correctly) - you just see an empty(!) `Spinner` with a non-empty dropdown list, and selecting an item does not have any effect.

So to fix your issue, you can either recreate a new adapter for the `Spinner` when `getAllChildExercisesFromParentID(List<String>)` is called. In this case you need to make the `Spinner` a field of your `Activity`, so that it can be accessed from this method:

```
private Spinner spinner;
```

Initialize it in `onCreate()` but don't set the adapter yet:

```
spinner =  findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Create a new instance of the adapter for the `Spinner` when you receive the data:

```
private void getAllChildExercisesFromParentID(List<String> allChildExercisesReceived){
    // maybe removing old data is a good idea?
    allChildExerciseNames.clear();

    allChildExerciseNames.addAll(allChildExercisesReceived);
 
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, allChildExerciseNames);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

}
```

Or you let your `Activity` have a field `private ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;`

Initialize the `Spinner` completely in `onCreate()`:

```
Spinner spinner =  findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, allChildExerciseNames);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

... and update the data list (and consequently the adapter) when you receive the data:

```
private void getAllChildExercisesFromParentID(List<String> allChildExercisesReceived){
    // remove old data 
    allChildExerciseNames.clear();

    allChildExerciseNames.addAll(allChildExercisesReceived);
    spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I like the second version better because it does not need to create a new object each time the data is refreshed - it can help to improve performance (but in this case the effect on modern devices will hardly be noticeable, so it's more a matter of code style)

BTW of course you can and should keep the `Spinner` in your layout - the `AppCompatSpinner` was just my attempt at getting rid of the weird "Landroid/widget/AbsListView..." message which just happened to pop up at the same time as the `Spinner` problem.

Comment: @Josh Brett - somewhere in your comments you mentioned Room and LiveData. Until then I had only patched something together in onCreate() and commented out most of your ViewModel-related code. Today I tried with a makeshift VewModel and so I stumbled across the missing `notifyDatasetChanged()` (as in the 2nd version). And I'm fairly sure that this is the cause for the misbehavior because now I can make it "not work" again simply by commenting out the `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

In `onItemSelected` you could do something like this after your log statement. Check if the view is of type spinner and if so set the selection to the index of the position you clicked.

```
if(view instanceof Spinner) {
  (Spinner)view.setSelection(position);
}
```

If your `onItemSelected` is only used by your spinner, you could take all the code out of `onItemSelected` and set the onClickListener directly for your spinner, that way the `instanceof` check isnt needed.

Comment: onItemSelectedListener is only for the spinner.  My log does not return anything, nor does the toast so I think the problem is to do with something else.

Answer (score 0):

It should work out of box. I think there is an issue with emulator, or old dependency in the project. Validate on real device too. **There might be alternatives, which I don't like too!**

**For ex.**

```
// .....
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    selectedExercise = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), selectedExercise, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("spinner item clicked ", selectedExercise);
    updateAdapter(selectedExercise)
}

// ....
private void updateAdapter(@Nullable final String selected) {
   final List<String> array = new ArrayList<>(allChildExerciseNames);

   if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selected)) {
       array.remove(selected)
       array.set(0, selected)
}
    
   final Spinner spinner =  findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
   final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new 
         ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array);
   

   spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter, array);
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
//...
```

Ps. You can get rid off some variables above by placing them as `Activity` class state. This solution was added by Your request, as alternative. At least you can use it, till we figure out the real issue.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I have ran the app on two emulators and both are having the same problem. Even after making your recommended alternate change, its still the same. I have updated all of my dependencies to their most recent version and I'm still having the same issue. Do you know of any other things that I could try?

Comment: I have also ran this on my real Huawei P20 Pro and the same error is occurring.

Comment: @JoshBrett Above workaround should work for sure. Please double check updated code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I copy and pasted your activity and XML from above compiled and ran on pixel 3xl emulator and it is working for me.

Note -  I have only commented and updated sections like framents, model and styles (in XML) that I didn't had. Please check if style of the spinner is the issue.

You can provide a custom UI to spinner as below.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerGenderAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.spinner_item, sp_gender);
    spinnerGenderAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mGenderSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerGenderAdapter);
    mGenderSpinner.setSelection(0);
```

spinner_item.xml

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="end"
android:textColor="@color/somecolor"
android:textSize="16sp" />'
```

[image: Activity]
[image: Gradle]

Comment: I am maually adding spinner items.                 private void getAllChildExercises() {

        allChildExerciseNames.add("Select exercise");
        allChildExerciseNames.add("3 sec squat");
        allChildExerciseNames.add("Plank");
        allChildExerciseNames.add("PushUps");
        allChildExerciseNames.add("Jogging");
        allChildExerciseNames.add("Run");
    }

Comment: Let me know if you are able to find the root issue.

Comment: Are you sure you have tested on device with API 30

Comment: I have ran the app on 2 virtual devices, as well as my own real phone, the same problem is occurring... Could this be something to do with the fact I am obtaining the values to go in the spinner from my ROOM database (liveData)?

Comment: Verified this on Android R API30...this is working shown in GIF above.

Comment: @joshBrett as shown in the image attached by you that your spinner list is being populated. However, on the selection of an item, you are unable to seen the toast or logs in logcat. I would have looked closely there.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your scenario programmatically in API 29. I believe this way you can get the default spinner behaviour.
What I did to reproduce your scenario was I override the default `getView()` implementation of the `ArrayAdapter` object.(I did it with my custom `simple_spinner_item_custom` layout but it should work with `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` too):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.simple_spinner_item_custom, spinnerStringArray) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                // get a reference to the textview from the item layout
                TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.custom_text_1);
                // I manually set the text to empty like this to reproduce :D
                // tv.setText("");
                // the fix I would like to suggest
                tv.setText(spinnerStringArray[position]);
                return view;
            }
        };
```

I also believe you can now set `onClickListener()` in this `view` object to get `onItemSelectedListener()` like behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create a new String array, make a new SpinnerAdapter and setAdapter (replace the old) to the spinner.